# Estimate for structural equation model

Tags: r, stata, structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable

I tried to find the estimate for SEM using R and Stata but I found that both estimates are different.

```
library(lavaan)
childfreq=as.numeric(data$bpfachildfreq)
childprob=as.numeric(data$bpfachildprob)
parentfreq=as.numeric(data$bpfaparentfreq)
parentprob=as.numeric(data$bpfaparentprob)
matrix=cbind(childfreq,childprob,parentfreq,parentprob)
cov=cov(matrix,use="pairwise.complete.obs",method="pearson")
n=nrow(data)
model<-'
FP =~ childfreq+childprob+parentfreq+parentprob
'
sem=sem(model,sample.cov=cov,sample.nobs =n)
```

Result from R:

[image]

`sem(FP->bpfachildfreq bpfaparentfreq bpfachildprob bpfaparentprob), stand`

Result from Stata:

[image]

Anyone knows how can I get the same result for both R and Stata? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do other things differ? Do the chi-square tests give the same value? Do you have any missing data, are you handling this differently?  In R, you are using pairwise deletion - I don't think you're using that in Stata.

Can  you check that your data are the same in both programs? In Stata, run

```
su
```

In R

```
summary(matrix)
```

You build the data in an unusual way.

What happens if you just run:

```
sem=sem(model, data)
```

It appe

Your variances seem very different, this can lead to precision problems. Multiply your variables by a constant.

You are asking for the standardized solution in Stata, not the regular (unstandardized) solution.

Comment: I have checked my data using summary and the data are same. I run my SEM model using lavaan package in R so my model need to be in following form: sem=sem(model,sample.cov=cov,sample.nobs =n). Yes, I asked for standardised solution in stata, I did ask for standardised solution in R as well.

Comment: Don't use pairwise deletion.Give Lavaan the data frame.

Comment: my data don't have missing data. I tried with complete.obs and I got the same result. I have also tried giving lavaan the data frame and I get the same results as sem=sem(model,sample.cov=cov,sample.nobs =n). Thank you!

Comment: You should not get the same results, because you analyzed a correlation matrix, not a covariance matrix.

Comment: do you mean STATA analyze using correlation? I used covariance matrix in R.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I missed that you used cov. But skip that step and just use the data.

Comment: yes I tried just using the data, got the same result when cov is used.

Comment: Can you post all the output, from both models?